# Angular JS Set focus and required validation, requires to click the link twice to open the link

Tags: angularjs, validation, focus, required

Please refer my HTML form attached

```js
var app =  angular.module('main_app',['ngRoute',"angucomplete-alt","ngStorage",'ui-notification','ngSanitize'])
   .factory('myService', function () {
    return {
     say: function ($scope) {
      return "Hello World";
     }
    }
   })
   ;
app.config(function(NotificationProvider) {
        NotificationProvider.setOptions({
            delay: 10000,
            startTop: 20,
            startRight: 10,
            verticalSpacing: 20,
            horizontalSpacing: 20,
            positionX: 'right',
            positionY: 'top'
        });
    });
app.controller('RegisterGuestController', function($scope,$routeParams,$http,$location,$rootScope,Notification){
 $scope.book_id = $routeParams.id_book;
 $scope.loginBlock = true;
 $scope.lostPassword = false;
 //console.log($scope.book_id);
 $http({
  url: base_url+"api_user/register_guest", 
  method: "GET",
  params: {book_id: $scope.book_id}
  }).success(function(data){
  if(data.return_code==1){
   $scope.bookDetails = data.data.bookDetails[0];
   //alert ($scope.bookDetails.name);
   $('#frm_name').focus();   
  } else {
   Notification.error({message: data.data.message, title: 'Error'});
  }
 }); 
  });
```

```html
<html><head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js"></script></head>
<body ng-cloak class="" ng-app="main_app" >
<div class="registration-page" ng-init="register_guest()" >
 <form method="post" id="registrationForm" name="frmregisterGuest" novalidate >   
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-6 ">
    <div class="form-group required" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : frmregisterGuest.frm_name.$invalid && frmregisterGuest.frm_name.$touched}" >
     <label for="txtfirstname">first_name</label>        
     <input type="text" name="frm_name"  value="" id="frm_name" class="form-control" ng-blur="validate=true" ng-model="frm_name" title="Enter your first name." required ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z']*$/" ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="20">
     <div ng-show="frmregisterGuest.frm_name.$error.pattern" class="help-block">Please enter only letters</div>  
     <div ng-show="frmregisterGuest.frm_name.$error.minlength" class="help-block">Min length of first name is 2</div>
     <div ng-show="frmregisterGuest.frm_name.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">Min length of first name is 20</div>
     <div ng-show="frmregisterGuest.frm_name.$touched && frmregisterGuest.frm_name.$error.required" class="help-block">Please enter first name</div>           
    </div>
   </div>   
   
   <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : frmregisterGuest.frm_middleName.$invalid && frmregisterGuest.frm_middleName.$touched}" >         
     <label for="txtmiddleName">middle name</label>         
      <input type="text" name="frm_middleName" id="frm_middleName" ng-blur="validate=true" ng-model="frm_middleName" class="form-control" title="Enter your middle name." ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z']*$/" ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="20">        
      <div ng-show="frmregisterGuest.frm_middleName.$error.pattern" class="help-block">Please enter only letters</div>  
      <div ng-show="frmregisterGuest.frm_middleName.$error.minlength" class="help-block">Min length of middle name is 2</div>
      <div ng-show="frmregisterGuest.frm_middleName.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">Max length of middle name is 20</div>          
     </div>
   </div> 
  </div>       
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-6">   
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : frmregisterGuest.frm_lname.$invalid && frmregisterGuest.frm_lname.$touched}">
     <label for="txtlastName">last name</label>         
     <input type="text" name="frm_lname" id="frm_lname" value=""  class="form-control"  ng-blur="validate=true" ng-model="frm_lname" title="Enter your last name."  ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z']*$/" ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="20">          
     <div ng-show="frmregisterGuest.frm_lname.$error.pattern" class="help-block">Please enter only letters</div>  
     <div ng-show="frmregisterGuest.frm_lname.$error.minlength" class="help-block">Min length of last name is 2</div>
     <div ng-show="frmregisterGuest.frm_lname.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">Min length of last name is 20</div>   
    </div> 
   </div>         
   <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group required" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : frmregisterGuest.frm_email.$invalid && frmregisterGuest.frm_email.$touched}">
     <label for="txtemail">email</label>
     <input type="email" name="frm_email" id="frm_email" value=""  class="form-control" title="Enter your email address." ng-blur="validate=true" ng-model="frm_email" required ng-pattern="/^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]{2,}$/"> 
     <div ng-show="frmregisterGuest.frm_email.$touched && frmregisterGuest.frm_email.$error.required" class="help-block">Please enter eamil</div>
     <div ng-show="frmregisterGuest.frm_email.$error.pattern" class="help-block">Please enter correct email</div> 
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group required" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : frmregisterGuest.frm_password.$invalid && frmregisterGuest.frm_password.$touched}" >
     <label for="txtpassword">password</label>
     <input type="password" name="frm_password" id="frm_password" value=""  class="form-control" title="Enter your password ." ng-blur="validate=true" ng-model="frm_password" required ng-minlength="6" ng-maxlength="10" >        
     <div ng-show="frmregisterGuest.frm_password.$touched && frmregisterGuest.frm_password.$error.required" class="help-block">Please enter password</div>
     <div ng-show="frmregisterGuest.frm_password.$error.minlength" class="help-block">Min length of password is 2</div>
     <div ng-show="frmregisterGuest.frm_password.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">Max length of password is 20</div>
    </div>
   </div>        
   <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group required" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : frmregisterGuest.frm_password2.$invalid && frmregisterGuest.frm_password2.$touched}">
     <label for="txtpassword2">confirm password</label>
     <input type="password" name="frm_password2" id="frm_password2" class="form-control" title="Enter your confirm_password." ng-model="frm_password2" required>  
     <div ng-show="frmregisterGuest.frm_password2.$touched && frmregisterGuest.frm_password2.$error.required" class="help-block">Please enter confirm password</div>
     <div ng-show="(!frmregisterGuest.frm_password2.$error.required) && frmregisterGuest.frm_password2.$touched && frmregisterGuest.frm_password2.$error.noMatch" class="help-block">password does not match</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>        
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
   <div class="form-group">
    <p class="lostpassword">
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="showBlock(1);">lost your password</a>
     or
     <a href="user/logout">already registered</a> 
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>  
  
  <div class="col-sm-6">
   <div class="form-group">
     <input type="hidden" id="bookId" name="bookId" ng-value="{{bookDetails.id_book}}" value="{{bookDetails.id_book}}">     
     <input type="button" ng-click="doRegister()" id="register" name="register" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="frmregisterGuest.$invalid" >        
   </div>
  </div>        
 </form>
</div></body></html>
```

I am setting focus to first field using following code in register_guest() JS function:
$('#frm_name').focus();

The form works fine When I am not using focus().

But by setting focus to first field, when I click the 'already registered' link, it displays 'required field error message' and does not redirect.
when I click second time on the same link, it redirects to required page.

I am using jquery version jquery-1.12.4 and AngularJS v1.4.1[enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 0):

try to use attribute autofocus inside  instead jquery focus()